# Does the value of specific heat capacity of a material differ at different surrounding temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics

I was looking for the exact theoretical value for specific heat capacity of copper. I found some telling 377, 385, 386, 390 J/kgK ... And for different room temperatures, 20 and 25 degree celsius, it shows different values on different websites.

So my question is "Does the value of specific heat capacity of a material differ at different surrounding temperature?"

..... or just simply due to different websites?

Note: I know that specific heat capacity, c is the property of material (different types of material will have different values of c, which indicates the amount of heat energy required to increase the temperature of 1kg object by 1K.

Comment: See update To my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was looking for the exact theoretical value for specific heat
> capacity of copper

I am not aware of there being an "exact theoretical value" of the specific heat of any solid material such as copper. (The specific heats of ideal or perfect gases are theoretically independent of temperature).

Experiments to determine specific heats have a certain degree of imprecision. Imprecision is the variability of the results of measurements from one experiment to another depending on the imperfection of the instruments, the experimenter and the possible variations of the environment of the measurements. See the following:

https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/imprecision

> I found some telling 377, 385, 386, 390 J/kgK (for copper)

The last three values are within 1.3% of one another. That may be due to the above mentioned experiment imprecision in connection with the sources of the information. The first value seems like an outlier. You didn't state whether all the sources involved the same experimental temperature range.

Then there is also the question of the “purity” of the copper. I have read that a material  should be at least 93% copper to be considered “pure”. Copper in electrical wiring that is not an alloy is supposedly 99.9% copper.

> So my question is "Does the value of specific heat capacity of a
> material differ at different surrounding temperature?"
>
> ..... or just simply due to different sources of information?

In view of the above, probably a bit of both.

In addition to the aforementioned possibility of experiment imprecision associated with the sources, and possible difference in purity, the specific heat of a material generally depends on temperature. For example, at the molecular level the specific heat can be effected by the three separate contributions of translational, rotational, and vibrational kinetic energy. Heat absorbed by a material can increase all three types of kinetic energy, but for a gas only the translational kinetic energy affects its temperature (kinetic temperature).

UPDATE:

NIST (US National Institute of Standards and Technology) gives the specific heat of pure copper at 300K as 386J/kg.K. It also gives different values at different low temperatures

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The specific heat capacity of a material is a property of the material, not the environment it is in. This is because the specific heat capacity just tells you by how much the temperature of the material changes when some amount of energy is added to it / taken away from it per unit mass. All that matters is the amount of energy, not where it came from.

However, many materials have specific heat capacities that depend on the temperature of the material itself, and this is most likely why there are different numbers for different temperatures.